# ember.js show default nested route if none provided

Tags: ember.js

In my ember app (1.0.0 production version) I have a URL structure as follows:

```
/item
/item/{specific-item-name-defined-in-routes}
```

The Router mapping looks a little like this:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource("item", function () { 
        this.resource("my-first-item");
        this.resource("another-item");
        ...
    });
});
```

If the user navigates to `/item` I want to display a specific post (e.g. `/item/my-first-item`).  I can do this by using the `redirect` method of the route:

```
App.ItemRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function () {
        this.transitionTo('my-first-item');
    }
});
```

Unfortunately with this approach if I manually type into the address bar the URL `/item/another-item` or navigate directly to `/item/another-item` the app redirects me to `/item/my-first-item`.  If I just change between nested routes (i.e. by clicking a link in the app it loads correctly).

How can I get the redirection to work around only when a nested route has not been provided?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of redirecting the item route, add the redirect hook to (the automatically generated) ItemIndexRoute:

```
App.ItemIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function () {
    this.transitionTo('my-first-item');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

## Update for ember-cli and pods structure

Mike Grassotti's answer is still correct but I wanted to also add an update about how to achieve this in Ember 2.x with ember-cli when using the new pods application structure. When using pods you need to create an `index` folder inside of the desired pod and then you can place a `route.js` file inside that index folder so the resolver can find it.

### Example Directory / File Structure

```
 pods
  ├─ application
  │   ├─ route.js
  │   ├─ controller.js
  │   └─ template.hbs
  └─ item
      ├─ index
      │    └─ route.js
      ├─ my-first-item
      │    ├─ route.js
      │    ├─ controller.js
      │    └─ template.hbs
      └── another-item
           ├─ route.js
           ├─ controller.js
           └─ template.hbs
```

### Example route.js

The `pods/item/index/route.js` file from above would be something like:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var ItemIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo('my-first-item');
  }
});

export default ItemIndexRoute;
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, according to the official documentation of [Ember 2.6](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/routing/defining-your-routes/)

A nested router like this:

`app/router.js`

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('posts', function() {
    this.route('favorites');
  });
});
```

Is the equivalent of:

`app/router.js`

```
Router.map(function(){
  this.route('index', { path: '/' });
  this.route('posts', function() {
    this.route('index', { path: '/' });
    this.route('favorites');
  });
});
```